# Is it possible to change the false state color of Angular Material's mdSwitch?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

Angular Material [md-switch](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/switch) Is an awesome directive. As i cannot find something relative in the documentation or generally in the web i was wondering if it is possible to change directive's background when is on a false state.

As you can see in the link above the md-switch can have color when it is on a true/active state. You can simply set this with an class or ng-class statement.

I would like though to have two colors let's say md-primary when my scope is true and md-warn when it's fasle.

For example:

```
<md-switch ng-model="status" aria-label="Status" ng-class="{'md-primary': status === true, 'md-warn': status === false}"></md-switch>
```

But this is not working.

Any ideas if somehow can do this without overriding manually the CSS?

ps: the status is changing there is no problem there ;)

Comment: You will have to override the css of classes as per the state..

Answer (score 13):

It's quite simple, actually:

```
/* 
 * The bar:
 */

md-switch .md-bar {
    background-color: #333; /* set not selected bar color */
}

md-switch.md-checked .md-bar {
    background-color: pink; /* set selected bar color */
}

md-switch[disabled] .md-bar {
    background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, .15); /* set disabled bar color */
}

/* 
 * The switch:
 */

md-switch .md-thumb {
    color: rgb(158,158,158); /* not selected switch color */
}

md-switch.md-checked .md-thumb {
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255); /* selected switch color */
}

md-switch[disabled] .md-thumb {
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255); /* disabled switch color */
}

/* 
 * Ripple effect
 */

md-switch .md-ink-ripple { 
   color: rgb(255,0,0); /* not selected switch ripple color */
} 
md-switch.md-checked .md-ink-ripple { 
   color: rgb(92,184,92); /* selected switch ripple color */ 
}
```

---

Updated response with the weakest CSS selectors to style `md-switch` states for Angular Material (checked on latest version: `1.0.0-rc7`).

If one wants this to be theme dependent, they would need to add the theme CSS selector on each each of the above (if you set a theme the "angular" way, the class applies itself to each angular material element):

```
md-switch[disabled].my-custom-theme .md-bar {...}
```

Comment: This has to be conditional..Otherwise `background-color: #333;` will be there irrespective of state..

Comment: Yes that's easy. I was wondering though if i can do it without manipulate the css but i guess i wasn't clear enough. Thanks though ;)

Comment: Also note `.md-switch` will return `null`..Valid selector is `md-switch .md-bar`(not class)

Comment: @RayonDabre there is a catch with this selector. It's not stronger than the ones the directive uses for its other states: i.e.: `md-switch.md-checked .md-bar` is for selected... You're right about right about `md-switch` html selector. silly me, posted without checking. Updated. :)

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, Perfect! Just `css` will do that..`ng-class` will not be needed..Good :)

Comment: Something like this: `md-switch.md-checked .md-bar {
    background-color: #ff0000!important;
}
md-switch .md-bar {
    background-color: #000!important;
}`

Comment: I would certainly not recommend the use of `!important` in this case. From where I see it, it would be like fixing a Swiss watch with a blacksmiths hammer.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu - thanks for the solution provided. Please note however on `md-switch .md-thumb` selector it must be also `background-color` property not `color` only

Comment: If someone uses ripple effect: `md-switch .md-ink-ripple { color: rgb(255,0,0); /* not selected switch ripple color */ } md-switch.md-checked .md-ink-ripple { color: rgb(92,184,92); /* selected switch ripple color */ }`

Comment: Thank you for the addition, @tstancin, I added it to the answer. To be honest, I am surprised this still works. I wrote it back when AngularJS was still at 1.3 or 1.4. A lot of things changed in both Angular and Angular Material since. Apparently, the switches stayed. :)